# Play framework 2 running unit tests in Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: java, scala, junit, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

There are two very similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106848/play-framework-2-running-junit-tests-in-intellij-idea) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810741/running-playframework-tests-as-a-intellij-idea-junit-run-configuration). I created a project with `play new` and ran `play idea`.  The tests run with the `play test` command and when I try to run them in IDEA I get the following stacktrace.

```
Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.pty4j.PtyProcess
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pty4j.PtyProcess
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.scala.play.jpsSupport.Play2TemplateJpsBuilder$$anonfun$build$1.apply(Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.scala:90)
    at com.intellij.scala.play.jpsSupport.Play2TemplateJpsBuilder$$anonfun$build$1.apply(Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:105)
    at com.intellij.scala.play.jpsSupport.Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.build(Play2TemplateJpsBuilder.scala:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1086)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:797)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:845)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:760)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:583)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:344)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:184)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have tried turning off the external compiler server in Settings (IDE) -> Scala, invalidating cache, and get the same exception. This is [jetbrains post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/) about the compiler server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the problem has not solved with 133.331. IntelliJ 13 still does not compile test codes.

I think it's due to external build, because there is no problem with IntelliJ 12 of which external build option is off.

Answer (score 0):

Updating IntelliJ from 13.0.1 133.330 to 13.0.1 133.331 fixed this issue for me.